# Unable To use PUT method to send data via CORS with Express

Tags: http, express, cors

I am working on simple web app on port 4000 with a RESTful API on port 8080. I have Express setup with the `cors` package and I seem to be sending the correct headers back from an OPTIONS request, see below:

```
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Content-Length: 0
```

This is returned with a status 204 ok. Then I see the PUT request in FF Network console and after about 45 secs the request header appears:

```
PUT /movies/updatemovie/59f4ee92be4becd967a573ca HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4000/movies
Content-Length: 151
Origin: http://localhost:4000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The request parameters are:

```
documentID=59f4ee92be4becd967a573ca&title=Captain%20America%3A%20Civil%20UnWar&release=2016&score=9&reviewer=%20Janet%20Garcia&publication=%20MoviesNow
```

Chrome shows the PUT as having failed after 4mins.

The Data is not getting posted to Mongo, nor do I get any response from the server.

Here is the relevant code:

Web App

```
$(".panel").each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).find("input[name = 'update']").is(":checked")) {
        updatedDocument = {
            documentID: $(this).data("id"),
            title: $(this).find("input#name").val(),
            release: $(this).find("input#release").val(),
            score: $(this).find("input#score").val(),
            reviewer: $(this).find("input#reviewer").val(),
            publication: $(this).find("input#publication").val()
        };
        JSON.stringify(updatedDocument);
        console.log(Object.values(updatedDocument));
    } // end if
}); // .each

// Now we have the document stored in JSON object, so lets form 
// an AJAX req and grab the updated data from our document and send
// a PUT to our API endpoint
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    data: updatedDocument,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/movies/updatemovie/' + updatedDocument.documentID,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json'
}).done(function (response) {
    // Check for successful (blank) response
    if (response.msg === '') {
        // do nothing
    }
    else {
        alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
    }
}); // end .done
```

API

```
/*
 * Put to Update movie.
 */
router.options('updatemovie/:id', cors());  
router.put('/updatemovie/:id', cors(), function(req, res) {
    const db = req.db;
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log(req.body.publication);

    const movieCollection = db.get("movies");
    const movieToUpdate = req.params.id; // Assign collection document id from url :id value
    const movieTitle = req.body.title;
    const movieRelease = req.body.release;
    const movieScore = req.body.score;
    const movieReviewer = req.body.reviewer;
    const moviePublication = req.body.publication;

     // Update the movie document from PUT info
    movieCollection.update({'_id' : movieToUpdate}, 
        {
            $set: {
              title: movieTitle,
              release: movieRelease,
              score: movieScore,
              reviewer: movieReviewer,
              publication: moviePublication
            }
        },
        function(err)  {
            res.send((err === null) ? {msg: ''} : {msg: err});
        }); // movieCollection .update

});
```

I get nothing from the console.logs in the API. Any suggestions most welcomed.

UPDATE: By removing line from APP `contentType: application/JSON` everything now works. I thought I wanted to send data as JSON to my API? Anybody who has any thoughts or input most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending the data as JSON. You've set the `content-type` header to `application/json` but the data will still be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To send JSON data using jQuery you'd need to encode it yourself:

```
data: JSON.stringify(updatedDocument),
```

On the server you'd then need a suitable `bodyParser` configuration:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

or:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

When you removed the line `contentType: 'application/json'` that header fell back to its default value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. That matches the format of the data and presumably you have `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())` or `app.use(express.urlencoded())` configured to parse that data. As your data is a flat string/string data structure it doesn't really matter which format you choose, you'll end up with the same values in `res.body`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly correct. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I was trying to send the updated movieCollection document back as JSON w/res.json(movieCollection) instead of the res.send(err) but I'm not able to. The Response is empty.  Would you have any suggestions on that?